# HTML Formatting

Tags: html, code-formatting

I have to make a few changes to some unformatted HTML (no line breaks, nothing) and was wondering if there are any web-based or open source tools that will automatically format it so it's easier to read.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) - overview from the documentation:

> When editing HTML it's easy to make
>   mistakes. Wouldn't it be nice if there
>   was a simple way to fix these mistakes
>   automatically and tidy up sloppy
>   editing into nicely layed out markup?
>   Well now there is! Dave Raggett's HTML
>   TIDY is a free utility for doing just
>   that. It also works great on the
>   atrociously hard to read markup
>   generated by specialized HTML editors
>   and conversion tools, and can help you
>   identify where you need to pay further
>   attention on making your pages more
>   accessible to people with
>   disabilities.

Comment: Tidy is great. This Firefox plugin based on Tidy is also nice to have: http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

Answer (score 6):

Check out Notepad++

In the menu, click TEXTFX -> HTML Tidy.

Comment: It uses Tidy HTML as a backend (tidy.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Your right, it does.  Great way to use Tidy HTML, tied right into the best lightweight editor out there.

Answer (score 0):

jedit also contains some plugins to do the job. (I think it is also using tidy)